# How to cycle focus and z-order of a given set of windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create a program which will cycle the z-order of a set of windows (the foreground window, along with windows which share a significant portion of their window area on the screen).

Let's say there are 4 windows, including the foreground window, that match this criteria. Invoking the program 4 times should bring each of the windows into the foreground in turn. This is my code:

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#undef min
#undef max

#include "enumWindows.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <format>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>


RECT getWindowRect(HWND hwnd) {
    RECT theRect;
    if (IsIconic(hwnd)) {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
        GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &placement);
        theRect = placement.rcNormalPosition;
    } else {
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &theRect);
    }
    return theRect;
}

bool isTopMostWindow(HWND hwnd) {
    LONG exstyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    return (exstyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) != 0;
}

int width(RECT const& r) { return r.right - r.left; }
int height(RECT const& r) { return r.bottom - r.top; }
int area(RECT const& r) { return width(r) * height(r); }

std::optional<RECT> intersection(RECT a, RECT b) {
    RECT theRect;
    theRect.left = std::max(a.left, b.left);
    theRect.right = std::min(a.right, b.right);
    theRect.top = std::max(a.top, b.top);
    theRect.bottom = std::min(a.bottom, b.bottom);

    if (width(theRect) <= 0 || height(theRect) <= 0)
        return std::nullopt;
    return theRect;
}

std::ostream& getLogStream() {
#ifdef CONSOLE
    return std::cerr;
#else
    static std::ofstream logFile("C:\\temp\\wincycle.log", std::ios::app);
    return logFile;
#endif
}

void debugPrintWindowOrder(std::vector<HWND> const& windowStack) {
    std::ostream& ostr = getLogStream();
    std::vector<HWND> sortedWindows = windowStack;
    std::sort(sortedWindows.begin(), sortedWindows.end());
    std::unordered_map<HWND, size_t> shortNames;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sortedWindows.size(); i++) {
        shortNames[sortedWindows[i]] = i;
    }

    for (auto window : windowStack) {
        ostr << shortNames[window] << ' ';
    }

    ostr << "  { ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sortedWindows.size(); i++) {
        ostr << std::format("{}={:06x}, ", i, (size_t)sortedWindows[i]);
    }

    ostr << "}\n";
}

void winCycle() {
    HWND fgWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    bool topmost = isTopMostWindow(fgWindow);
    if (fgWindow) {
        std::vector<HWND> windowStack;

        auto fgWindowRect = getWindowRect(fgWindow);
        float fgWindowArea = (float) (width(fgWindowRect) * height(fgWindowRect));

        enumTaskbarWindows([&](HWND hwnd) {
            if (topmost == isTopMostWindow(hwnd)) {
                auto windowRect = getWindowRect(hwnd);
                if (auto interOpt = intersection(fgWindowRect, windowRect)) {
                    auto const& intersection = *interOpt;
                    float windowArea = (float) area(windowRect);
                    float intersectionArea = (float) area(intersection);

                    // greater than 90% overlap
                    if (intersectionArea > 0.9 * fgWindowArea && intersectionArea >= 0.9 * windowArea) {
                        windowStack.push_back(hwnd);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        debugPrintWindowOrder(windowStack);

        if (windowStack.size() > 1) {
            auto hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos(windowStack.size());
            for (size_t i = 0; i < windowStack.size(); i++) {
                size_t stackIndex = (i + 1) % windowStack.size();
                HWND insertAfter = HWND_TOP;
                if (i != 0) {
                    size_t prevIndex = (stackIndex + windowStack.size() - 1) % windowStack.size();
                    insertAfter = windowStack[prevIndex];
                }
                hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, windowStack[stackIndex], insertAfter, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
            }
            EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);

            SetForegroundWindow(windowStack[1]);
            if (IsIconic(windowStack[1])) {
                ShowWindow(windowStack[1], SW_NORMAL);
            }
        }

    }
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    winCycle();
}
```

The `enumTaskbarWindows()` function is defined in `"enumWindows.h"`. It invokes [`EnumWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) and attempts to filter out windows which aren't in the taskbar. Ideally, it should give the same windows you get with Alt-Tab. I'm not entirely sure if it does that job correctly, but regardless, it is so far giving me the windows I expect, and more importantly, it should be giving me the windows in the same order as `EnumWindows()`, just with some filtered out. If you need to see it, I will provide that below.

I've compiled this program, and hooked it up with a keyboard shortcut using AutoHotKey. When I run the program several times, it does, eventually, cycle through all of the expected windows. However, instead of just going to each window in order, there are some windows that get the foreground multiple times before some other windows get it.

I've created the `debugPrintWindowOrder()` function to help see what's happening. What it does is assign each window handle a small integer, and show the order in which those windows appear in the stack. Here is some sample output from the program. Each line corresponds to the program running 1 time:

```
3 1 0 2   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
1 2 3 0   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
2 3 0 1   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
3 0 1 2   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
0 2 3 1   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
2 3 1 0   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
3 1 0 2   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
1 2 3 0   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
2 3 0 1   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
```

The hexadecimal number there is the actual window handle. But I assign each a shorter 1 digit identifier so I can see the change in z-order better. Notice that each invocation, the window handles are identical, and getting assigned to the same shortened id. If the program was working corretly, I should see this:

```
3 1 0 2   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
1 0 2 3   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
0 2 3 1   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
2 3 1 0   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
3 1 0 2   { 0=020318, 1=0204f2, 2=4f0cc6, 3=6e0998, }
```

Each time, pushing the front window to the back, and repeating after 4 invocations. But that is not happening.

The code of most interest here starts in the `wincycle()` function, after the call to `debugPrintWindowOrder()`. At that point in the code, `windowStack` should have a list of the window handles that match my criteria, in the order they came from `EnumWindows()`. And `windowStack[0]` should be the foreground window. And as far as I can tell, that is the case.

My cycling algorithm is pretty straight-forward. I am starting at `windowStack[1]` (which should be the next window in z-order below the foreground window), and then going up through `windowStack[2]`, `windowStck[3]`, etc... Then looping around at the end to `windowStack[0]`.

So, am I using the `DeferWindowPos()` functions correctly here? Or `SetForegroundWindow()`? Why are the windows not being re-ordered in the way that I expect?

Here is `"enumWindows.h"`, if you want to see that:

<!— language: c++ —>

```
#ifndef ENUM_WINDOWS_202208261917
#define ENUM_WINDOWS_202208261917

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace enum_windows_details {

    inline HWND getLastVisibleActivePopUpOfWindow(HWND window) {
        int const maxLastActivePopupIterations = 50;
        int level = maxLastActivePopupIterations;

        HWND currentWindow = window;
        while (level-- > 0) {
            HWND lastPopUp = GetLastActivePopup(currentWindow);
            if (IsWindowVisible(lastPopUp))
                return lastPopUp;
            if (lastPopUp == currentWindow)
                return NULL;
            currentWindow = lastPopUp;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    inline bool eligibleForActivation(HWND hwnd, HWND shellWindow) {
        if (hwnd == shellWindow)
            return false;
        
        HWND root = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);

        if (getLastVisibleActivePopUpOfWindow(root) != hwnd)
            return false;

        char classNameBuffer[256];
        int length = GetClassNameA(hwnd, classNameBuffer, sizeof(classNameBuffer));
        if (length == 0)
            return false;
        std::string className = classNameBuffer;

        char const* classNamesToSkip[] = {
            "Shell_TrayWnd",
            "DV2ControlHost",
            "MsgrIMEWindowClass",
            "SysShadow",
            "Button",
            "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow",
            "ApplicationFrameWindow"
        };

        for (auto toSkip : classNamesToSkip) {
            if (className == toSkip)
                return false;
        }

        {
            char buffer[] = "WMP9MediaBarFlyout";
            int buflen = sizeof(buffer) - 1;
            if (className.size() >= buflen) {
                if (memcmp(buffer, className.c_str(), buflen) == 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    template<typename HandlerFunc>
    BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowFunc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
        HandlerFunc* pHandler = (HandlerFunc*) lParam;
        (*pHandler)(hwnd);
        return TRUE;
    }
} // namespace enum_windows_details

template<typename HandlerFunc>
void enumWindows(HandlerFunc handler) {
    using namespace enum_windows_details;
    EnumWindows(&enumWindowFunc<HandlerFunc>, (LPARAM) &handler);
}

template<typename HwndHandler>
void enumTaskbarWindows(HwndHandler handler) {
    using namespace enum_windows_details;
    HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();

    int currentPid = GetCurrentProcessId();

    enumWindows([&] (HWND hwnd) {
        if (!eligibleForActivation(hwnd, shellWindow))
            return;
        DWORD windowPid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &windowPid);

        if (windowPid == currentPid || GetWindowTextLengthA(hwnd) == 0)
            return;

        LONG exstyle = GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        if (exstyle & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW)
            return;

        handler(hwnd);
    });
}

#endif // #ifndef ENUM_WINDOWS_202208261917
```

Comment: Have you checked what the Windows API functions return?

Comment: @SimonMourier: I was checking the return values of the Defer functions, and SetForegroundWindow. I never saw them fail, and have since deleted the checks.

Comment: Unrelated to the immediate issue, but there's [`IntersectRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-intersectrect) so you don't have to write your own.